# What is the UK standard E14 LED Candle bulb and holder for the US, is it E12?

Tags: led

I am making a table lamp and I'm going to try and mass produce it. I live in the UK but I will be selling in the US, does any one know the differences in voltage/wattage and light bulb holders? I am using a E14 LED Bulb UK, bought from IKEA and what I can see in IKEA US with the same light is a E12 LED Bulb does is that about right? Also I am using a Brass light holder with an earth, is this somthing that is standard in the US or would I have to look at a differen holder, maybe plastic? 
Thanks for any help on this, most appreciated!

Comment: According to - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edison_screw - the E12 is used in the US (but for some reason, the "peer" for the E14 is the larger E17 ... I guess that makes sense ... I suspect that there may be current limits for the different sizes of base, and for a given maximum wattage in a bulb size (not a factor for LED, obviously) you'd need a larger contact area for 120V vs 240V

Answer (score 1):

E26 is used for most lamps in the USA. Incandescent bulbs have been available in that base for 120 volts rated in the range 7-1/2 W or less to 500 W or more. Today, the widest variety of LED bulbs are made with that base. The base is much larger than necessary for the most-used power ratings in incandescent bulbs. For CFL and LED bulbs that size base may more easily accommodate the required electronic circuitry. The most competitively priced LED bulbs seem to be the ones rated to replace 60W incandescent bulbs. The base insulating material and other parts apparently limit many fixtures to 60 W maximum incandescent. Thermal considerations also tend to limit CFL and LED bulbs to  the 60 W equivalent.

Most table and floor lamps are "double insulated" as required for use with 2-conductor, cords and plugs with no ground pin. I believe that the entire product needs to have an independent testing laboratory label such as UL or ETL.

Answer (score 0):

I hate LED light bulbs.  Two problems with LED light bulbs.

1. Powered by AC
2. Too much heat per sq. inch

Why is everyone stuck in the days of Thomas Edison?

Unlike Incandescent Light Bulbs, LEDs need DC current. I would like to see houses wired for DC lighting.  The voltage should be 48 volts (more efficient than 12).

LED efficiency and longevity are highly temperature dependent. By cramming LEDs into the confines of a "Light Bulb" generate too much heat with costs us in both light per watt and life span of the bulb.

The only lamp I would buy today would be a DC powered LED lamp where the LEDs are sufficiently spread apart. I would prefer the number of LEDs to around 16 to accommodate a 48 volt supply.

A DC powered lamp could circumvent the need for regulatory approvals if powered by a brick.

### The answer to your question is E12 Candelabra.

While E26 is the most common base E12 is used in low watt light bulb commonly used for kitchen and dining room fixtures (chandeliers), and accent lighting.

E12 makes a lot more sense for LED lighting.  With the lower Luminance per bulb you will be spreading the heat rather than concentrating it in an E26 bulb.

[image]